# JPA is returning my entity with ONLY the id populated, all other fields are null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mariadb

JPA is returning my entity with ONLY the id populated, all other fields are null (as verified by the debugger). It is fetching the entity by doing a search on another column using a JPA Query, which results in the entity having an id of 13 (which is correct) but the rest of the fields *are* populated and defined in the db as not null, any ideas as to why this is happening would be great.

[I had a bunch of code listed but as it does not contribute to the answer (well more precisely the question) I removed it.]

Comment: I'm not sure the question should be closed, it was rather unusual, there are quite a few duplicates of "org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of" however assigning wrapper types will not resolve this issue. Also some were insisting that primitive types should be valid, which in this case they were, meaning others may have seen this but didn't find a solution. Unless someone can find a duplicate of this case.

Comment: I'm getting this weird behavior right now on a Postgres database. After adding create_date and last_update fields it returns only the ID values, the  other fields are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I was getting an error of "`org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of`" however the issue was that the entity was assigning nulls to all fields but the id (which are certainly not null and by constraint can not be).

The issue was I edited the DB schema to make a timestamp field not null, but MariaDB(MySQL) had assigned '0000-00-00 00:00:00' to that column. For some reason no errors, or warning were generated, it just happily returned an entity with only the id (the primary key) set!

I only found my mistake when I tried to persist, and it informed me that I had to persist the now required timestamp field, after updating the method used to save the entity, I reviewed the contents of the db and found the error (column containing '0000-00-00 00:00:00').

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem recently, it looks like spring data does some kind of instantiation.

I just change Cascade Type from MERGE to PERSIST and my issue resolved.
As Persist and merge are designed as a way to keep one managed instance of certain object.If you use persist it means the object does not exist yet, so making it a unique managed instance doesn't hurt.

When you use merge, you take into consideration that a managed instance of the object may already exist. You don't wanna replace that unique managed instance, because some other object might reference it, believing it is the managed object.